# Any LaTeX editor recommendations to use with Moodle?

Tags: texmaker

I just started using TeX via TexMaker (and MiKTeX) so I could enter more complex text on Moodle for a Linguistics class; however, I've noticed a couple differences, e.g.,

Shows up fine in TexMaker: `\text{The squirrely} \overbrace{\hbox{ \textbf{children}}}^{\hbox{NP/S/Agent}}`

Need $ symbols to make boldface work in Moodle: `\text{The squirrely} \overbrace{\hbox{ $\textbf{children}$}}^{\hbox{NP/S/Agent}}`

Also, I know Moodle uses ( ) instead of $ signs to indicate TeX.

This means I can't use TexMaker to create and then just copy from TexMaker to Moodle without modifications.  Is there a better editor for this or a way to configure TexMaker to use with Moodle?  I don't know much about the permutations of TeX, but I saw maybe there are different versions, so I suppose this is the problem...  Thanks!

Comment: Moodle doesn't actually use LaTeX, but MathJax. While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site.  You might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Comment: There is no simple solution here.  However, you need to carefully read the Moodle documentation on their implementation of LaTeX constructs.  https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Using_TeX_Notation  Caution: I doubt you will every be able to simple copy and past source between Moodle and compilable LaTeX without having to manually adjust items.

Comment: Okay, got it ...kind of.  :)  Thanks for taking the time to help!  I guess need to be looking more for a good MathJax editor.  I'll check out the links you guys posted.